# Software interrupt on network traffic

Tags: linux, events, interrupt

On my computer there is 3G, Wifi and LAN port. I would like to build a linux software to show green color if there is network traffic and red color for no network traffic.

TCPDUMP could provide the real time statistics but it would generate high CPU load. Therefore I wonder if I could get the real time statistics via software interrupt? Whenever there is network traffic a software interrupt will be generated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't put redundant tags in titles. You also likely need to specify the language you're using to tell the computer what to do.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will go and check. By the way is netfilter module run under kernel space or user space? Thanks in advance

Comment: @GrantThomas I can learn any programming language to achieve my objective. But before talking about the implementation I would like to know the feasibility - does linux provide network traffic event trigger for a program to catch on userspace?

Comment: @Winston the netfilter module runs in kernel space. its a kernel module. but you can use kernel IPC methods to communicate with your user space program. check this [nice tutorial](http://www.paulkiddie.com/2009/10/creating-a-simple-hello-world-netfilter-module/) . But be careful. I think it could be a security issue if non privileged user space programs can obtain too much information from that module

Comment: @Winston In that case this is an off-topic non-programming question and not suitable for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether you'd call this a software interrupt, but you could consult the following example. (The third argument to poll() is the time in milliseconds after which the network is considered inactive.)

```
/* compile with -lpcap */
/* run as root         */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <pcap.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int color = 0;
    struct pollfd ufd;
    struct pcap_pkthdr h;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t *p = pcap_open_live(NULL, 0, 0, 0, errbuf);
    if (!p) return puts(errbuf), 1;

    ufd.fd = pcap_fileno(p);
    ufd.events = POLLIN;
    for (; ; )
        switch (poll(&ufd, 1, 100))
        {
        case -1:    perror("poll"); return 1;
        case  0:    if  (color) color = 0, puts("red"); break;
        default:    if (!color) color = 1, puts("green");
                    pcap_next(p, &h);
        }
}
```